# Free shared memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

Is there any application level API available to free shared memory allocated by CTA in CUDA? I want to reuse my CTA for another task and before starting that task I should clean memory used by previous task.

Comment: Shared memory does not persists between kernel calls: what is your problem? In general it is far better to launch a new kernel than trying to accomplish more (heterogenous) tasks in the same kernel.

Comment: I want to use same CTA for another task so I'm planning to sync with `__syncThreads()` and use it for another task.

Comment: Stefano, kernel fusion is a time-honored way to amortize kernel launch overhead in CUDA.

Comment: @archeasoftware ok, but just to keep things in perspective we are speaking of about 10 or 20 microseconds for synchronous launches and even less for async. launches. Sorry for not stating explicitly that I avoid kernel fusion for my personal programming style preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shared memory is statically allocated at kernel launch time.  You can optionally specify an unsized shared allocation in the kernel:

```
__global__ void MyKernel()
{
    __shared__ int fixedShared;
    extern __shared__ int extraShared[];
    ...
}
```

The third kernel launch parameter then specifies how much shared memory corresponds to that unsized allocation.

```
MyKernel<<<blocks, threads, numInts*sizeof(int)>>>( ... );
```

The total amount of shared memory allocated for the kernel launch is the sum of the amount declared in the kernel, plus the shared memory kernel parameter, plus alignment overhead.  You cannot "free" it - it stays allocated for the duration of the kernel launch.

For kernels that go through multiple phases of execution and need to use the shared memory for different purposes, what you can do is *reuse* the memory with shared memory pointers - use pointer arithmetic on the unsized declaration.

Something like:

```
__global__ void MyKernel()
{
    __shared__ int fixedShared;
    extern __shared__ int extraShared[];
    ...
    __syncthreads();
    char *nowINeedChars = (char *) extraShared;
    ...
}
```

I don't know of any SDK samples that use this idiom, though the threadFenceReduction sample declares a `__shared__ bool` and also uses shared memory to hold the partial sums of the reduction.

Comment: Kernel fusion can work well, but be wary of register usage.  The number of registers allocated for the kernel is static across the kernel launch, also, so any part of your larger kernel that has higher register requirements will decrease the occupancy of the whole kernel accordingly.